# problems with sig handling of SIGSEGV

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have created a signal handler to get called when SIGSEGV is sent.  I am using C to write my programs and also using Linux and intel x86 processor.  In the sig handler it looks like the si_addr that is passed in through the siginfo_t struct is given the value 0 instead of the value of the address of the instruction causing the problem.  I set the SIG_INFO flag in sigaction so idk why this is happening.

Here is some example code:

```
int main(){
    mprotect(..., PROC_READ | PROC_WRITE /* | PROC_EXEC */);  //cannot execute page

    someMethodOnRestrictedPage();
    //do some stuff
}

void init_sighandler(void) {

    //initialize the sigaction so that sig handler is called when a SIGSEGV is thrown
    struct sigaction * action;

    action = (struct sigaction *) malloc(sizeof(struct sigaction));

    action->sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    sigemptyset (&action->sa_mask);

    action->sa_flags = 0;

    sigaddset(&action->sa_mask, SA_SIGINFO);
    sigaddset(&action->sa_mask, SA_RESTART);

    sigaction(SIGSEGV, action, NULL);
}

void sighandler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *ucp){
    printf("%x\n", siginfo->si_addr);   // prints out 0
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: why are you trying to handle segmentation faults?  What do you intend to do in your handler?

Comment: I am restricting access to certain memory pages for it to intentionally create a SIGSEGV then I am handling it

Comment: It would probably be helpful to know what platform you are on, and if you could post a minimal test program that would be great.

Comment: What else is in siginfo when sighandler is executed?

Comment: http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/siginfo_t.5.asp

Comment: that has a look at the stuff in the siginfo_t struct

Comment: All other variables seem to be 0 as well.  I have not tried them all though.  Its like the struct was initialized but never filled with anything.

Comment: Is the output different if you use `%p` instead of `%x`? Pointers should use `%p`, not `%x`, and printf may be reading junk instead of useful values.

Comment: The `sigaddset` calls are misusing `SA_SIGINFO` and `SA_RESTART`.  Those are flags meant for the `sa_flags` field.  The sa_mask is a set of *signal numbers* (e.g., SIGSEGV, SIGILL, etc) of signals to block during your handler.  (You can leave this set empty in your case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.sa_flags` has the `SA_SIGINFO` bit cleared.

Quoting http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigaction.html,

SA_SIGINFO

If cleared and the signal is caught, the signal-catching function will be entered as:

`void func(int signo);`

where `signo` is the only argument to the signal catching function. In this case the `sa_handler` member must be used to describe the signal catching function and the application must not modify the `sa_sigaction` member.

If `SA_SIGINFO` is set and the signal is caught, the signal-catching function will be entered as:

`void func(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context);`

where two additional arguments are passed to the signal catching function. The second argument will point to an object of type `siginfo_t` explaining the reason why the signal was generated; the third argument can be cast to a pointer to an object of type `ucontext_t` to refer to the receiving process' context that was interrupted when the signal was delivered. In this case the `sa_sigaction` member must be used to describe the signal catching function and the application must not modify the `sa_handler` member.

The `si_signo` member contains the system-generated signal number.

The `si_errno` member may contain implementation-dependent additional error information; if non-zero, it contains an error number identifying the condition that caused the signal to be generated.

The `si_code` member contains a code identifying the cause of the signal. If the value of `si_code` is less than or equal to 0, then the signal was generated by a process and `si_pid` and `si_uid` respectively indicate the process ID and the real user ID of the sender. The `<signal.h>` header description contains information about the signal specific contents of the elements of the `siginfo_t` type.

--End quote

So sigaction uses `.sa_handler` if the bit is clear, and `.sa_sigaction` if the bit is set.

So you have undefined behaviour, since you're reading unwritten arguments.

Set `.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | ...` to rectify the issue.

Comment: yes, thank you!  I thought all I needed was the sigaddset(&action->sa_mask, SA_SIGINFO); to set it but I guess not.